# How make categories relationships with several model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have next models: Articles, Announcements, Catalogs and Media.

For item of every model I need to create a subcategory and a category. I will plan to create a relationship table with two columns: `parend_id` and `child_id`, and a column for every model with `category_id`.

How many relationship models I should create?

- One for all?
- Or one relationship model for every model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a relationship model instead just use `belongs_to` relationship

because you said following i guess belongs_to relations should do it

> For item of every model I need create subcategory and category.

So just add `subcategory_id` and `category_id` in your tables: Articles, Announcements, Catalogs and Media and establish `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship

**EDIT** But if you insist for relationship model then I would suggest to use one relationship model for every model.

**Last EDIT:** I really think you should use belongs_to, has_many relation

```
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :subcategory
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  # the same relation(has_many) will be for Announcements, Catalogs and Media

  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  belongs_to :category
end
```

In this way you can get all articles using `category.subcategories.articles`

If the `category` has only one `Subcategory` then change the relation between them to `has_one` and your syntax will become `category.subcategory.articles`

Comment: How best to organize the relationship between categories and subcategories? I think what if i will create relationship model for every model, i will able to use `catecory.subcategory.articles` request

Comment: I have a question Articles will have only one `subcategory` and one `category` right?

Comment: @Uandі, yes, User should select category, next select subcategory and see list of articles

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship with a polymorphic association in a single join table:

```
#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizable_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizable_categories
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable,dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :tags
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: :tags, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Article'
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This will allow you to call the categories for each model with the likes of `@article.categories`

To achieve the parent & child categories, I'd recommend using something like the [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) - you'd set up an ancestry column in your join table - basically allowing you to create relations between a model's categories directly